# the path to a point in a matrix. Want to solve it by DP

Tags: c, dynamic-programming

The given matrix is the problem matrix. With cell 0,0 marked as 2 to show the entry point. We have to find the path to reach element 9. I have used recursive backtracking and marked the valid path as 2 that will lead to the element 9. Can someone help me in implementing it using DP.

```
include <stdio.h>
int path(int [][7],int ,int);
static int exitstack=0;
int main(void) {
    int result,i,j;
    int arr[7][7]={
    {2,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {0,1,1,0,0,0,1},
    {0,1,0,1,1,0,1},
    {1,0,9,0,1,1,1},      //the problem matrix
    {1,0,1,0,1,1,0},
    {1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,1}
    };
    path(arr,0,0);

    for(i=0;i<7;++i)
    {
        for(j=0;j<7;++j)
            printf("%d",arr[i][j]);

        printf("\n");

    }

    return 0;
}

int path(int p[7][7],int x,int y)
{
    int i;
    if(p[x][y]==9)
    {
        exitstack=1;
        return 1;
    }

    for(i=1;i<=4;++i)
    {

        if(i==1) //moving right
        {


            if((y+1)<7)
            {
                if(p[x][(y+1)]==9)
                    path(p,x,(y+1));

                if(p[x][(y+1)]==1)
                {
                    p[x][(y+1)]=2;
                    if(path(p,x,(y+1))) 
                        return 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if(i==2) //moving up
        {

            if((x-1)>0)
            {
                if(p[(x-1)][y]==9)
                    path(p,x-1,y);

                if(p[(x-1)][y]==1)
                {
                    p[x-1][y]=2;
                    if(path(p,x-1,y))
                        return 1;

                }

            }   
        }


        if(i==3) //moving left
        {

            if(y-1>0)
            {
                if(p[x][(y-1)]==9)
                    path(p,x,y-1);

                if(p[x][(y-1)]==1)
                {
                    p[x][(y-1)]=2;
                    if(path(p,x,y-1))
                        return 1;

                }
            }
        }
        if(i==4) //moving down
        {

            if(x+1<7)
            {
                if(p[x+1][y]==9)
                    path(p,x+1,y);

                if(p[x+1][y]==1)
                {
                    p[x+1][y]=2;
                    if(path(p,x+1,y))
                        return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }   

    if(p[x][y]==9)
    {

        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if(exitstack==1)
            return 1;
        else
        {
            p[x][y]=0;  
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the abbreviation "DP"?

Comment: Are you interested in a particular path or will an arbitrary path be sufficient? In the latter case, DFS will be sufficient.

Comment: i want to find the shortest possible path. With my code, i am just able to find one path, that may or may not be the shortest.

Answer (score 0):

If you by DP mean dynamic programming, you could try to use the D* algorithm. It's a bit too long to describe here, but you can read more about it here (http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ggordon/likhachev-etal.anytime-dstar.pdf) or here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D*), or google it.